# How do I get git to display the changes in vim as hg does with the hgeditor script?

Tags: git, vim, mercurial

An interesting feature in mercurial is the ability to view the changes that will be committed in a vim split (see [DiffsInCommitMessageInVIM](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/DiffsInCommitMessageInVIM)).

Any hint on how to do so with git ?

Comment: Note that the `core.editor` is used not only for commit, but also for tag, add (interactive), and commit -e.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you've got syntax enabled, Vim detects git commit messages as a filetype. This should be obvious from highlighting. The much less obvious part is that it also has a filetype plugin for git commits (and other git things). Make sure you have those enabled (`filetype plugin on`), and then there will be a helpful command defined: `DiffGitCached`. Just run that, and it'll toss a diff into a preview window.

A comment next to the definition of that command in the plugin:

> Automatically diffing can be done with:
>
> `autocmd FileType gitcommit DiffGitCached | wincmd p`

The filetype plugins are stored in /vimXX/ftplugin/git*.vim, e.g. `/usr/share/vim/vim70/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`, if you're curious to have a look!

Comment: Doing a `diff commit` and in vim `:set ft=gitdiff` then `:DiffGitCached`, I do have a window opening, but without any information in it.

Comment: @Alexis: You shouldn't have to set a filetype. Git should detect it and enable the plugin automatically, as long as you have `filetype plugin on` in your vimrc. And, you don't really need to know this, but the filetype for git commit messages is `gitcommit`, not `gitdiff`.

Comment: even without specifying the filetype (and I can see that the filetype is detected by vim, regarding the highlighting), the `DiffGitCached` does not seems to work. Strange.

Comment: @Alexis: Hm, it works fine for me. Troubleshooting... the command is defined, right? It tries to run, and pops up a preview window? If it's empty, it suggests that either you don't actually have any changes staged (unlikely) or that it wasn't able to run the appropriate git command... What happens if you just do `!!git diff --cached`? That is, directly invoke the git command in your commit message window.

Comment: aaah ! it was the auto change directory option of my vimrc wich was causing troubles :) Thanks for the help !

Comment: I prefer to use `... | wincmd L`, it docks the diff buffer on the right hand side.

Comment: @AlexisMétaireau could you post here what option you had to disable to make this work?

Comment: Well, this was almost 5 years ago and I honestly don't remember :(

Answer (score 2):

I've modified the HGEDITOR.SH script to support Git, you can clone it here:

```
git clone git://github.com/dharrigan/giteditor.git
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Hey David! :) Just what I was looking for! (Alessandro)

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend tpopes's `vim-fugitive` plugin for working with git.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using git 2.9 and above, you can get this behaviour by running `git config --global commit.verbose true`.

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37848889/112538).

Answer (score 0):

I use [Pierre Habouzit's git.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1934) from www.vim.org.  Drop it into ~/.vim/ftplugin and you should be all set (assuming the usual `filetype plugin indent on` in your ~/.vimrc).