# `git commit -v` by default

Tags: git

How can I configure `git commit` to act as `git commit -v` (showing the full diff being committed) by default?

Using an alias is not quite satisfactory, as it does not affect commit message editing during operations which may indirectly commit, such as `git rebase`.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you are using git 2.9, this can be done with a config.

```
git config --global commit.verbose true
```

Git 2.9.0 Release Notes: 
https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.9.0/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt

> "git commit" learned to pay attention to the "commit.verbose"
>      configuration variable and act as if the "--verbose" option
>      was given from the command line.

Comment: This is great but it can be problematic under certain extreme diffs. For those you can temporarily disable `verbose` like so `git -c "commit.verbose=false" commit`

Comment: @CervEd Thanks for that great tip! I had no idea you could override config options on a per commit basis. Thanks!

Comment: *If you are using git 2.9 ...* Ah .. so this is why it doesn't work on my CentOS 7 server. It only has version 1.8.3.1. That's why I was looking for the option (searched Google for the commit.verbose = 2). Have a +1. What's curious though: in < 2.9 you can do git commit -v and it functions just as well .. or at least it did. I'm not sure why it does not now. Maybe I was mixing it up with something else. That's also possible. Anyway thanks for specifying version - that's helpful!

Comment: Additionally, they work in aliases `alias puc = -c push.default=current push -u`

Comment: @Pryftan that's pretty normal. Usually these types of configurations act as if `-v` was supplied by default

Answer (score 30):

As far as I can tell, you can not override an already existing git command with an alias (otherwise, there would be no way to do the original command, and a bunch of stuff would break).

So I recommend you do something like `git config --global "alias.ci" "commit -v"`.  This will add a line to your `~/.gitconfig` file and make it so that `git ci` does `git commit -v`.  You should then just get into the habit of typing `git ci` instead of `git commit` (unless you decide you don't want the `-v`).

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it's the best solution I've seen, but it seems the actual answer to my question is “No, there is no way to set git commit to default to verbose” — which, note, is not the same for 'breaking stuff' as replacing an arbitrary command with another.

Comment: I see.  I didn't consider that there might be a configuration option to do it.  But all the configuration options are heavily documented in the `git-config` man page, and I did not see anything there that might let you do this (you can double check yourself if you like).  So I think that there is not a way to make `git commit` do `git commit -v` directly.

Comment: As of v1.8.4-rc1, there is no such configuration option (see [builtin/commit.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/304852fc77847e649c746db95e9c4675c03ee567/builtin/commit.c#L1581), the `verbose` global is only set via the `OPT__VERBOSE` option)

Comment: Someone wrote [a patch to add this](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/commit-support-commit-verbose-and-no-verbose-td7611617.html) as a configuration option to git, but no one accepted it.

Answer (score 9):

Well, I use aliases:

```
alias gc='git commit -v'
```

There are a bunch of nice aliases like this that I got off the PeepCode git screencasts, I believe.

Comment: @MatrixFrog: `git gc` is a Git command, `gc` by itself doesn't do anything.

Comment: Right, nevermind. You meant a regular alias, not a git alias. Which is obvious now that I'm actually paying attention. :P

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I happened to come across it and have an answer. I put the following function in .bash_profile:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                            

git()                                                                                  
{                                                                                      
    case "$1" in                                                                       
        ci|commit)
        gitargs=""
        for i in $@; do
            if [ "$1" != "$i" ]; then                                                  
                gitargs="$gitargs $i"
            fi  
        done
        command git commit -v $gitargs
        ;;  
    *)  
        command git "$@"
        ;;                                                                             
    esac                                                                               
}
```

This turns `git` into a bash function that transforms `git commit` into `git commit -v` and leaves the rest of the arguments mostly alone. However, it breaks `git commit` arguments that have whitespace, and it won't let you commit a file named `ci` or `commit`.

Comment: It would be nice if `git-commit` was its own separate command, so that just that could be overridden.

Answer (score 4):

I just sent an e-mail to `git@vger.kernel.org` and got the following response:

> 05.04.2016 16:47, Pranit Bauva:
>   On Tue, Apr 5, 2016 at 8:08 PM, Jacek Wielemborek  wrote:
>
> > Hello,
> >
> > I'm asking for this one because there's quite a lot of interest
> >     (including me) in this feature and there is no convenient walkaround:
> >
> > [`git commit -v` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875275/git-commit-v-by-default)
> >
> > Cheers,
> >     d33tah
>
> This is currently under progress. I am the one who is working on it.
>   One of the patches is currently on the pu branch. I am still polishing
>   it to include some more stuff. You can track its status by reading the
>   git.git messages by the git maintainer. The latest revision of the
>   patch is at http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/288820
>
> Thanks,
>   Pranit Bauva

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the update and link. If this gets into a future release I'll be sure to update the accepted answer here — as soon as I notice, anyway, as I'm not in the habit of checking git release notes. Nudge me if you hear more!

Comment: @KevinReid: you can always apply the patch today ;)

Answer (score 2):

The following put in `.bashrc`/`.profile` seems to do the job:

```
git() {
    if [[ "$1" = "commit" ]]; then
        shift
        command git commit -v "$@"
    else
        command git "$@"
    fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks @boshvark for the inspiration.  Not sure what your whitespace issues were, but this doesn't seem to have any.

Comment: This won't help with indirect commits like during rebasing.

Comment: Interesting point.  Maybe time to submit a patch to git then.

Answer (score 1):

Silly workaround: `:!git log -1 -u`

Comment: As stated, this doesn't help. While the editor is open, `git log -1 -u` will display the patch of HEAD, not the one currently being committed. That said, `git diff HEAD` does do the trick. Hm, I should check what happens in e.g. a rebase.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't generalize; for example, in a rebase `squash`, which is the case of most interest to me, it would have to be `git diff HEAD~n`. Know any way to get the diff of _the specific commit operation in progress_?