# How do I make commit diff appear in commit message while I'm editing it (with Vim)?

Tags: git, vim

My biggest bottleneck in vim is the moment when I need to write a commit. Often, i do not remember the diff. First I write "git diff". Then I write "git commit" but, ... "Hey! I do not remember ...". Thus, I need to stop to write commit message, then I come back and run diff message. Sometimes I work with two windows: on the left I run "git diff". On the right I run "git commit". This allow me to write a commit message complete, while I can watch the diff of each file, ... and so on.

Can someone help me to improve this moment in vim workflow?

Comment: `git commit -v` to see the diff in vim while commiting

Comment: @FDinoff, you should post your comment as an answer so that the OP can accept it.

Comment: Make sure you take a look into [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)

Comment: `commit -v` is definitely the answer, but if you'd like to enhance your experience, try [committia.vim](https://github.com/rhysd/committia.vim).  This plugin shows diff, status, and a window for editing commit message.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `git commit -v` to see the diff in vim while committing.

```
-v, --verbose
    Show unified diff between the HEAD commit and what would be
    committed at the bottom of the commit message template. Note
    that this diff output doesn't have its lines prefixed with #.
```

Comment: +1 This is what I always use. I wish there was a way to make it default behavior

Comment: @mvp There doesn't appear to be away currently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875275/git-commit-v-by-default

Answer (score 3):

The `ftplugin/gitcommit.vim` that ships with Vim has a `:DiffGitCached` command, which opens the diff in a split scratch buffer. I've assigned a quick mapping to it (in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`):

```
nnoremap <LocalLeader><LocalLeader> :DiffGitCached<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `git commit -p` to see all the changes being made before committing them. See `man git commit`

```
-p, --patch
    Use the interactive patch selection interface to chose which changes to commit.
    See git-add(1) for details.
```

---

Edit: See @Fdinoff's comment on your question for a better way.

Answer (score 0):

For those using [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) use `:Gcommit -v` or use `cvc` mapping in the `:Gstatus` window.

See the following for more information:

```
:h :Gcommit
:h :Gstatus
```