# Git alias using full command

Tags: git, alias

I'm curious as to whether any git command may be aliased using the full original command, since this method could be used to add default options to commands.

For example, I'd like to add an alias for `git commit` to append the --verbose option. However, I don't want to shorten the commit command; I like the intentional need to type the full command since commits should be fully considered.

Thus, I would like to use (I'm in Powershell)

`PS C:\> git config --global alias.commit = "commit --verbose"`

but the alias is added to my config as `alias.commit = =`.

I also tried

`PS C:\> git config --global alias.commit = "!git commit --verbose"`

This actually adds the command to my config but the alias still doesn't work.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: My intention was to point out that this won't work for any command, not just the specific use case of commit. Searching for the more generic "alias any git command" yielded no results. I will re-word my question because I think it's worth having an answer to the more generic titled question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As I was typing this up I did a bit of extra research on specifically setting verbose on commit instead of just searching for ways to use full commands as aliases. Turns out my specific use case has been answered: [`git commit -v` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875275/git-commit-v-by-default). Git >2.9 has a setting to force `git commit` to use verbose mode: `git config --global commit.verbose true`.

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6482493/1047941) by [@asmeurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161801/asmeurer) to the same question does mention aliasing commit. They speculate that it is not possible to alias using full commands because things could be broken quite easily. Thinking higher-level this of course makes sense, I just was not considering this possibility.

Comment: I feel like this answer is just rehashing  the answers to the duplicate.

Comment: My intention was to point out that this won't work for any command, not just the specific use case of commit. Yes, it restates the answers in the duplicate, but searching for the more generic "alias any git command" yielded no results.