# How to make DiffGitCached work with "autochdir" set in vimrc?

Tags: git, vim

I follow the answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785163/how-do-i-get-git-to-display-the-changes-in-vim-as-hg-does-with-the-hgeditor-scri). If you look at the comments, it doesn't work if you have the `set autochdir` in your `.vimrc`. However, I still want both to work together, is there a way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this autocmd to disable `autochdir` when editing a git commit message:

```
autocmd BufRead COMMIT_EDITMSG setlocal noautochdir
```

Comment: did you try it on your machine? I think I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: @BPm Yes, this is the config I have been running for several months. I can't claim it will work for everyone, but it works for me.

Comment: Having `setlocal` here does not make much sense: `'autochdir'` is a global option, so `setlocal noautochdir`, `set noautochdir` and `setglobal noautochdir` give the same result, but `setlocal` is misleading as well, making you think you set a local value only.

Answer (score 1):

Small hack:
`autocmd BufRead COMMIT_EDITMSG cd .. | DiffGitCached`