# How to set the correct path for a file in VIM?

Tags: python, vim, path

Whenever I hit `:pwd` in vim the command always returns the path `C:\Windows\system32`, even if I'm in a Python file from the desktop. So whenever I run `:!python %` the command returns

```
python: can't open file '\Users\myname': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

But if I set the path with the command `:cd %:p:h` and then run the same python command the Python file executes correctly. So basically I'm wondering how do I get vim to correctly set the path for every file that I open.

*(i.e. if I'm in a file located at the desktop `:pwd` returns `~\Desktop\` or if I'm in a file in the home directory `:pwd` returns `C:\Users\MyName\`)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set `autochdir`:

```
:set autochdir
```

With this setting the current working directory will follow the file that you're editing.

See `:help 'autochdir'`, and particularly this note:

> Note: When this option is on some plugins may not work.

Comment: @user1163114 I don't know of any specific issues. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491883/how-to-make-diffgitcached-work-with-autochdir-set-in-vimrc) at least one question about an incompatibility with a particular `filetype` plugin.