# How to change current path in Vim automatically?

Tags: vim, macvim

When I type in terminal something like

```
mvim ./path/to/my/project
```

Vim opens this project directory, in my NERDTree I can see files, but when I try to run some CLI command, like

```
:!touch some/file/in/my/project
```

It occurs, that my current path is my users home directory

so if I want to create file in my project dir, I must type full path like

```
:!touch ./path/to/my/project/some/file/in/my/project/name
```

Is it possible somehow to automatically change dir after vim starts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the correct path for a file in VIM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022142/how-to-set-the-correct-path-for-a-file-in-vim)

Comment: I think not, autochdir doesn't solve my problem.
I want to change dir to the root of my project, and nothing more.

Comment: The `:pwd` is supposed to be the directory in which you invoked Vim. Or `~` if you just launch GVim/MacVim.

Comment: I use vimprj plugin, and I had to disable the "feature" of aways comming back to the vimprj root directory because I didn't like it (`g:vimprj_changeCurDirIfVimprjFound = 0`). You may like this default behavior.

Answer (score 5):

For your particular use case you could try hooking something up on the VimEnter event. For example, try putting this in your vimrc:

```
autocmd VimEnter * cd %:p:h
```

Then, when you invoke Vim with `$ mvim path/to/my/project/some/file` Vim will automatically `:cd` into the directory `file` is in.

For this to work with directories you will have to add a little logic to the autocommand, e.g.

```
autocmd VimEnter * exe 'cd '.(isdirectory(expand('%:p')) ? '%:p' : '%:p:h')
```

You can improve on this yourself!

Answer (score 4):

I use this in my vimrc:

```
" Use %% on the command line to expand to the path of the current file
cabbr <expr> %% expand('%:p:h')
```

Answer (score 3):

How to best solve this depends on your exact use case. I'm partial to `:set autochdir`, but if you want the working directory set to the project root, I'd use one of the *local vimrc* plugins (I use [localrc.vim - Enable configuration file of each directory](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393)), create a local `.vimrc` file in each of your project roots with

```
:cd expand('<sfile>:p:h')
```

in it. Then, regardless of which file within the project hierarchy you open, the working directory will always be set to the project root.

Answer (score 1):

in_vimrc

```
au BufEnter * silent! lcd %:p:h
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command

```
:cd %:p:h
```

https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file